# ABPFramwork - Remove api from layer application in swagger

Tags: abp

I have created a project using abpframwork. When running swagger, swagger receives the function in the application layer is a api. I don't want that. Can you guys tell me how to remove it in swagger

Code in Application Layer

```js
public class UserService : AdminSSOAppService, ITransientDependency, IValidationEnabled, IUserService
    {
        IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly ILogger<UserService> _log;

        public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository,
            ILogger<UserService> log
            )
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _log = log;
        }

        public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetList()
        {
            var list = await _userRepository.GetListAsync();
            return ObjectMapper.Map<List<User>, List<UserDto>>(list);
        }

        public async Task<UserDto> GetUserById(int Id)
        {
            var user = await _userRepository.GetAsync(c=>c.Id == Id);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<User, UserDto>(user);
        }
    }
```

Code in HttpApi Layer

```js
[Area(AdminSSORemoteServiceConsts.ModuleName)]
    [RemoteService(Name = AdminSSORemoteServiceConsts.RemoteServiceName)]
    [Route("api/user/user-profile")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase, IUserService
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userAppService;
        public UserController(IUserService userAppService)
        {
            _userAppService = userAppService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get-list-httpapi")]
        public Task<List<UserDto>> GetList()
        {
            return _userAppService.GetList();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get-by-id-httpapi")]
        public Task<UserDto> GetUserById(int Id)
        {
            return _userAppService.GetUserById(Id);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you might be confusing the application layer with the service/manager layer. If I may ask, why do you not want methods in the application layer not to be available in swagger? If you check the abp docs, APIs are created dynamically and are exposed.

Comment: @EvramEhab I want config route outside class => '[Route("api/user/user-profile")]'. 
Class in application (UserAppService) not implement ControllerBase. I can only configure route in HttpApi layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest a workaround as to enable only the APIs you need to appear on swagger (though the ones that don't appear anymore will still be available for consumption).

I would suggest you add a configuration part in your *.Http.Api project module inside your `ConfigureSwaggerServices`, like so:

```
context.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.DocInclusionPredicate(
            (_, apiDesc) =>
                apiDesc
                    .CustomAttributes()
                    .OfType<IncludeInSwaggerDocAttribute>()
                    .Any());
    });
```

And for the attribute, it would be very simple, like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class IncludeInSwaggerDocAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

This will let you achieve what you want, however I still recommend reading the doc carefully to be able to implement DDD.